# Changing Font Size of (the Appearance of) Comments

Tags: support

Is it possible to change the font size when viewing Comments, which appears smaller than those in Questions and Answers? If not, would it be possible to render this as a personalised option?

I hope to avoiding having to zoom in or out on my browser for every new page/browser tab.